# Loading non-English texts is n-times slower than loading English texts in WebClients

Tags: android, webclient

I tried to load Andersen's article "The ugly duckling"(which is HTML) into WebClient on Android, here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setupWebClient();
    }

    private void setupWebClient() {
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        String html = readTestHtml();
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i("test", String.format("Cost %dms", end - start));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Read HTML from "/sdcard/Download/test.html", which is "The ugly duckling" in Chinese.
     */
    private String readTestHtml() {
        File downloads = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File file = new File(downloads,"test.html");
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
}
```

The loaded article is written in Chinese. It took 7654ms to finish loading. However, when I replaced the article with the English version, it was much faster, which only took 375ms to finish it. It seems that WebClient has some trouble parsing Chinese characters. Is there anything I can do to make it faster to parse Chinese characters?

Test materials and device:

- The article in English: http://hca.gilead.org.il/ugly_duc.html
- The article in Chinese: http://www.dushu369.com/tonghua/HTML/2425.html
- Test phone: Pixel 1

Notice that x86-based emulators don't have this problem. I can only reproduce this problem on real phones.

Comment: Have you eliminated network latency as a possible culprit?

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, because you don't need the network to run the code. It just read HTML from files and loaded it in WebClient.

Comment: Hmm. Is it faster on subsequent loads?

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, it's a lot faster on subsequent loads for the same contents.